# Highly compressing a grid of numbers

Tags: c++, c

I have a square grid which contains numbers and I need to compress it a lot so it can easily be transferred over a network. For instance, I need to be able to compress a 40x40 grid into less than 512 bytes, regardless of the values of the numbers in the grid. That is my basic requirement.

Each of the grid's cells contains a number from 0-7, so each cell can fit in 3 bits.

Does anyone know of a good algorithm that can achieve what I want?

Comment: See [Lossless compression algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lossless_compression_algorithms).

Comment: To use simple bit-width limits you'd require 2.56 bits per grid element... you're going to need to use a more complex compression scheme. Are there any other patterns in the data?

Comment: So, 600 bytes is not good enough.

Comment: No, unfortunately, 600 bytes is not good enough.

Comment: @oldrinb, the data is mostly random, but at times can be mostly zeroes. I don't want to count on that, though, since I need the data to be under 512 bytes all the time. Can you explain a bit more on the bit-width limits of 2.56?

Comment: @myrkos 2^9 bytes = 2^12 bits, 2^12 bits / 40^2 elements = 2.56 bits/element. You need a pattern between elements (be they adjacent or whatever other relation) so that the average necessary information per element is less than or equal to *2.56* bits -- any patterns could be helpful here.

Comment: @myrkos: You have 4800 bits of data, so you can have 2^4800 different messages. You can only fit 2^4096 messages into 512 bytes. *Something* will have to give.

Comment: e.g. if it were generated by a pseudorandom number generator, you could merely send the initialization vector. Patterns present in the information that decrease entropy will enable you to implement an effective lossless compression algorithm.

Comment: myrkos: @KerrekSB is right. There is no way you can guarantee that the size will be under 512 bytes if your messages are completely random.

Comment: Okay, if this isn't possible, then how many bytes would it need to be at minimum? Is it 600?

Comment: @myrkos yes; 40^2 elements * log2 8 bits/element / 8 bits/byte = 600 bytes

Comment: Yes, 600 bytes suffices: Group every eight consecutive numbers into three bytes, 200 times.

Comment: So, 600 bytes *is* good enough after all.

Comment: "I need the data to be under 512 bytes all the time" -- That's an impossible condition; some set of values will require at least 4800 bits. This is a fundamental theorem of information theory. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: @JimBalter yep, which is why we need to find patterns so he doesn't need to transfer as much information :-)

Comment: @oldrinb Patterns don't help reduce the *maximum* data size, which remains >= 600 bytes. That is her or his "basic requirement". As stated in the pigeonhole principle article, "The principle can also be used to prove that any lossless compression algorithm, provided it makes some inputs smaller (as the name compression suggests), will also make some other inputs larger".

Comment: Can you state why you are unable to deliver it in two packets rather than one?  I'm assuming you have a 512 byte limit on packets.  But is this due to a volume/throughput issue?

Comment: @paddy: it's basically a protocol design limitation, and it seems splitting messages into multiple packets may make things much more complex. I may have to resort to that in the end, though.

Comment: @myrkos Maybe more complex, but possibly not more complex than a magical compression algorithm ;-)

Comment: @JimBalter yes, clearly... I'm familiar with math. My point was that if you *know* there exists a consistent pattern in all versions of the grid, you can exploit it to reduce the needed amount of information to transmit :-) since he said it was "mostly random", I figured he meant he just didn't recognize a pattern yet. If the values were truly arbitrary, then, yes, you wouldn't be able to compress it effectively.

Comment: See, I just don't think I can rely on patterns when the grid can change through multiple users' actions. Yes, it is a game.

Comment: @oldrinb Your point was clearly well known by myself and the others who commented here, and was irrelevant for the reason stated. 'he said it was "mostly random"' -- in the same comment in which he **or she** said that, he **or she** said "I don't want to count on that, though, since I need the data to be under 512 bytes **all the time**."

Comment: 'See, I just don't think I can rely on patterns when the grid can change through multiple users' actions.' -- Indeed. Patterns and compression are irrelevant; this has been clear all along.

Comment: If this is state for a game, perhaps you can get the compression you need by sending the difference between two states rather than the entire grid.

Comment: @user315052 I doubt that. If you just send plain difference between two versions of grid numbers - then you need in total `4 bits` per cell - 1 additional bit for sign (+7 / -7). You may of course try not to send cells which doesn't differs. But that means that receiver of changed cells must know the positions of received cells. Now imagine how you will send position of cell in 40x40 grid in a 3 -bit number ? - No way.

Comment: So the only feasible way is to construct that 600 byte array and pass it through some stream compressor - such as deflate in gzip. If you need compression in embedded environment I would suggest [gziplite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gziplite/). But there are plenty of other implementations. (And of course you will not escape from the information theory as others pointed)

Comment: @0x69 The practicality of using difference depends on how many cells can change all at once. If only one cell can change, then the message for the difference is only the changed cell and the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your information differently. You dont't need to assign all numbers 0 to 7 a code with the same number of bits. You can assign based on number of times in the sequence.

First read the whole sequence counting the number of appearances of every number.
Based on that you can assign the code to each number.
If you assign the code following for example [Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) the codes will be prefix code, meaning there is no extra character to separate numbers.

There are certain variations that you can introduce on the algorithm based on your test results to fine tune the compression ratio.

I used this technique in a project (university) and it provides, in general, good results. At least it should approximmate your theoretical 3 bits per character and can be much better if the distribution of probabilities helps.

Comment: The OP said "regardless of the values of the numbers in the grid". Regardless of the encoding, there's always going to be some set of values that requires at least 600 bytes (40x40x3/8).

Comment: You are right, I got confused, I thought there were seven values, not 8, hence if all the values appear with the same probability there will be 3 bits per value. I edit.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the problem as stated is not possible as 600 bytes are required to represent all possible grids. 600 bytes is from 40 rows, 40 columns, 3 bits per cell, and 8 bits per byte (`40 * 40 * 3 / 8`). As Kerrek SB explained in the comments, you pack 8 cells into 3 bytes.

In your own comments, you mentioned this was game state being transferred over the network. Assuming you have a mechanism to assure reliable transport of the data, then if there is a reasonable limit to the number of cells that can change between updates, or if you are allowed to send your updates when a certain number of cells change, you can achieve a representation in 512 bytes. If you use 1 bit to represent whether or not a cell has changed, you would need 200 bytes. Then, you have 312 remaining bytes to represent the new values of the cells that have changed. So, you can represent up to `312*8/3 = 832` modified cells.

As an aside, this representation can represent up to 1064 changed cells in less than 600 bytes.

Comment: This will work as long as you're using TCP. If you're using UDP for low latency updates you can't guarantee that you'll get every delta.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: Word. Edit made reflecting assumption of reliability.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is perform a "burrowes-wheeler" transform on your data, and then compress it. Run-length encoding will be enough in this case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform

This will likely outperform huffman in your case.

It is true that in some cases you will need more than 512 bytes. So in your protocol just make an exception for "perverse" grids. But in the general case you should be under 512 easily.